# yii2 Error of dynamic client validation URL - Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, yii2-validation

I add a field dynamically using jquery and then dynamically add the field to the validation list as shown in the link ([Adding and removing fields dynamically](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/#adding-and-removing-fields-dynamically)). In my code, I add url validation.

```
function validateDynamicField() {
    $('#serial-form').yiiActiveForm('add', {
        id: 'link-1-link',
        name: 'link-1-link',
        container: '.field-link-1-link',
        input: '#link-1-link',
        error: '.help-block',
        enableAjaxValidation: true,
        validate:  function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
            yii.validation.required(value, messages, {
                "message": "Name be blank bug."
            });
            yii.validation.url(value, messages, {
                "message": "Name must be a url."
            });
        }
    });
}
```

At client url validation of a field appearing errors:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined** in [yii.validation.js](https://gist.github.com/ricco381/dd8f573626e3a76b130477f4df7fb241).

This error appears on line 244:

`if (!valid || !options.pattern.test(value)) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you need to provide the pattern against which it would validate the URL, as you are calling the `validation.url` the complete options that you should pass

```
{
    "pattern": /^(http|https):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(?::\d{1,5})?(?:$|[?\/#])/i,
    "message": "Name must be a url.",
    "enableIDN": false,
    "skipOnEmpty": 1
}
```

`enableIDN`: Whether the validation process should take into account IDN (internationalized domain names).

if you add a `console.log(options);` in the start of the function `url` in the file `yii.validation.js` and then go inside any form where you have a URL field added normally with a rule inside the model as url, for instance, if you have a `website` field in the model the rule should look like `[['website'],'url']` then pressing the submit button with empty inputs you will see `console.log(options)` output as the same as above which are adapted via core validator-rules.

So change your code to

```
function validateDynamicField() {
    $('#my-form').yiiActiveForm('add', {
        id: 'link',
        name: 'link',
        container: '.field-link',
        input: '#link',
        error: '.help-block',
        enableAjaxValidation: true,
        validate:  function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
            yii.validation.required(value, messages, {
                "message": "Name be blank bug."
            });
            yii.validation.url(value, messages, {
                "pattern": /^(http|https):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(?::\d{1,5})?(?:$|[?\/#])/i,
                "message": "Name must be a url.",
                "enableIDN": false,
                "skipOnEmpty": 1
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. You helped me a lot. And thanks for editing the question.

Comment: No Problem @Pavel we are all here to help each other, glad it helped you out. happy SO.